# Retrieving items left in Thalmor Embassy

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I entered the Thalmor Embassy and had all my good stuff stashed somewhere, but I couldn't find the chest where it was. so now I completed the mission using only magic, but I cant get back in the embassy. Does anyone know how to get back in or a way I could get my stuff back? I'm on a PS3 not PC so I can't just use command to get it back. any help would be appreciated. I couldn't find a way back in without glitches. I also cannot just re load the save because that save is now overwritten by another save.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [The Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thalmor_Embassy) there are 3 ways of doing it:

> **Gaining Access After "Diplomatic Immunity"**
>
> There are several ways to enter the embassy (including locked areas) after the completion of Diplomatic Immunity. Keep in mind that these tricks require several tries to succeed. Tested and works on PS3.
>
> - Use wooden plate on the wall to the left side of the main entrance (behind the lamppost). Keep running into the plate to bypass the wall into Elenwen's Solar exterior. Difficulty: Easy.
> - Enter the embassy via backdoor. There's a locked door at the center of the first floor that leads directly into the party hall. Use another wooden plate on the door. Again keep running into it until you can see the other side of the door, then immediately use Whirlwind Sprint to enter the hall. Razelan and Brelas (occasionally Elenwen and Illdi) can be found here. Difficulty: Easy to Hard.
> - Entering the kitchen area from the party hall requires two plates (or one from the center hall). Use the same trick as above with Whirlwind Wind on the first door, and another one at the hallway into the kitchen. Tsavanni will have generic conversations with the Dragonborn instead of warning them about it's against the rules to be in the kitchen. Difficulty: Easy to Hard.

Comment: Would these be considered glitches, or is that the purpose of the plates? it's been years since I was at this point, and I definitely never tried to re-enter after the quest.

Comment: @TimS. There's no official way to get back to Thalmer Embassy after you complete that quest so yes, this involves exploiting the game's engine or exploiting glitches as you put it.

Comment: Ah okay. I was just curious. I remember leaving in a hurry, and I'm sure there were tons of useful stuff in there. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @TimS. The linked wikia page has a list of notable loot in the location.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this method worked and i got all my stuff back now!XD

Comment: @SkyrimKat111 glad I could be of assistance :).